# Counting number of columns with same text in given row

Tags: sql-server

I am fairly new to SQL and could use some help.

For each row in a table, I have a number of columns containing text. I want to count how many columns for a given row contain the same text string. What is the syntax for that?

I thought about converting the text string I am searching for to 1 and adding across a given row, but wasn't sure the syntax for that either.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Need some clarification.  Is there a set number of columns?  Are you looking for the number of columns that match a certain input? Or are you just looking for the number of columns that match each other?  What if there are two columns that match each other and two different columns that match each other?

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes, there are around 12 columns. They all contain a standard 4 options of text - "a", "b", "c", "d". I want to count all of the columns for row 1 that have contain text "a".

Comment: then the answer given is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) Statement

```
Select case when column1 = 'Text' then 1 else 0 End+
       case when column2 = 'Text' then 1 else 0 End+
       ...   As Count_Of_Col_Text
From Yourtable
```